Encode and Decode Decklink SDI with FFMPEG
Has anyone ever setup a encode/decode pair using FFMPEG and Decklink SDI Cards? (or any other capture cards). The end goal is to bring in a remote camera feed into the studio switcher so quality and low latency is important.  There is a private ethernet network already setup between the two studios.
I'm testing using this on the encoder (10.40.0.100)
ffmpeg -f decklink -video_input 'sdi' -i 'DeckLink SDI (1)' -f mpegts  udp://10.40.0.111:8090

and on the receiving computer (10.40.0.111) currently on the same network as the encoder. I'm just trying to playback using ffplay (eventually this will output to another decklink)
ffplay -f mpegts udp://10.40.0.111:8090

but the playback is unstable and I get all these errors.  I'm sure I have some settings wrong but no idea what.
[mpeg2video @ 0x7a6fcc0c7500] Invalid mb type in I-frame at 0 30
[mpeg2video @ 0x7a6fcc0c7500] Warning MVs not available
[mpeg2video @ 0x7a6fcc0c7500] concealing 540 DC, 540 AC, 540 MV errors in I frame
[mpegts @ 0x7a6fcc000cc0] PES packet size mismatchsq=    0B f=0/0   
[mpegts @ 0x7a6fcc000cc0] Packet corrupt (stream = 1, dts = 7109221).
[mpeg2video @ 0x7a6fcc0c7500] ac-tex damaged at 20 19
[mpeg2video @ 0x7a6fcc0c7500] Warning MVs not available
[mpeg2video @ 0x7a6fcc0c7500] concealing 540 DC, 540 AC, 540 MV errors in P frame
[mpegts @ 0x7a6fcc000cc0] Packet corrupt (stream = 1, dts = 7113541).
[mpegts @ 0x7a6fcc000cc0] Packet corrupt (stream = 0, dts = 7116984).
[mpeg2video @ 0x7a6fcc0c7500] end mismatch left=1060 8893 at 0 31   
[mpeg2video @ 0x7a6fcc0c7500] Warning MVs not available
[mpeg2video @ 0x7a6fcc0c7500] concealing 0 DC, 0 AC, 0 MV errors in P frame
[mpegts @ 0x7a6fcc000cc0] Packet corrupt (stream = 1, dts = 7117861).
[mpegts @ 0x7a6fcc000cc0] Packet corrupt (stream = 1, dts = 7122181).
[mp2 @ 0x7a6fcc0c9680] Header missingB vq=  456KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
[mpeg2video @ 0x7a6fcc0c7500] end mismatch left=1124 9380 at 0 31
[mpeg2video @ 0x7a6fcc0c7500] Warning MVs not available
[mpeg2video @ 0x7a6fcc0c7500] concealing 0 DC, 0 AC, 0 MV errors in P frame
[mpegts @ 0x7a6fcc000cc0] Packet corrupt (stream = 1, dts = 7126501).
[mpegts @ 0x7a6fcc000cc0] Packet corrupt (stream = 1, dts = 7130821).
[mpeg2video @ 0x7a6fcc0c7500] end mismatch left=1060 8893 at 0 31   
[mpeg2video @ 0x7a6fcc0c7500] Warning MVs not available
[mpeg2video @ 0x7a6fcc0c7500] concealing 0 DC, 0 AC, 0 MV errors in P frame
[mpeg2video @ 0x7a6fcc0c7500] ac-tex damaged at 16 25    0B f=0/0   
[mpegts @ 0x7a6fcc000cc0] Packet corrupt (stream = 1, dts = 7139461).
[mpegts @ 0x7a6fcc000cc0] Packet corrupt (stream = 0, dts = 7144011).
[mpeg2video @ 0x7a6fcc0c7500] ac-tex damaged at 41 30
[mpeg2video @ 0x7a6fcc0c7500] Invalid mb type in I-frame at 0 20
[mpeg2video @ 0x7a6fcc0c7500] Warning MVs not available
[mpeg2video @ 0x7a6fcc0c7500] concealing 1260 DC, 1260 AC, 1260 MV errors in I frame
[mp2 @ 0x7a6fcc0c9680] Header missing
    Last message repeated 1 times
[mpegts @ 0x7a6fcc000cc0] Packet corrupt (stream = 1, dts = 7143781).
[mpegts @ 0x7a6fcc000cc0] Packet corrupt (stream = 0, dts = 7153020).

Any guidance would be appreciated.

All those errors relate to damaged or missing data i.e. errors during transmission, not ffmpeg processing. Try with modern codecs -c:v libx264 -preset veryfast -bf 0 -c:a aac

Thank you for the guidance. I was able to successfully encode using:  ffmpeg -f decklink -video_input 'sdi' -i 'DeckLink SDI (1)' -c:v libx264 -preset veryfast -tune zerolatency -bf 0 -c:a aac -f mpegts udp://192.168.100.10:8080 I'm able to playback on 192.168.100.10 using ffplay but ultimately I'd like to be able to playout using another blackmagic card. I can play out a local video file with ffmpeg -i videofile.mp4 -f decklink -pix_fmt uyvy422 'DeckLink SDI (1)' but I can't figure out how to playout the receiving stream to the SDI output

You have to change the output from -f mpegts udp://192.168.100.10:8080 to -f decklink -pix_fmt uyvy422 {Decklink out card}
